# Google fonts choppy in firefox

Tags: firefox, webfonts, google-webfonts

My win 8 Firefox 41.0.1. shows many googlefonts choppy even in the preview. After implementing on my page the result is obviously the same. Is this an issue for a lot of users and I should rather use webfont kits?

page in the thumbnail: https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Comfortaa

[image: choppy even on preview]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with all Google fonts. Here is an example of one working good even in the mentioned version of Firefox:

https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans

Linking to Google fonts means linking to Google-hosted webfont kits and behaves similarly as those self-hosted. No guarantee of cross-browser functionality. One has to check them in all browsers.